# Return value while using closure as a Completion Handler In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

```
func loadMoreData(offset: Int, completion: (result: [ArtistJSONMapper]?) -> Void) {

    var fetchedData = [ArtistJSONMapper]()
    let pageNum: Int = offset/paging.limit

    // Calling the json fetch to obtain data

    JSONFetch.jsonTest() { (fetched, error) -> Void in
        if(fetched != nil) {
            fetchedData = fetched!
            //self.tableView.reloadData()

        } else {
            println("error - \(error)")
        }
    }

    println("Fetched data count is \(fetchedData.count)")
    completion(result: fetchedData.count > 0 ? fetchedData : nil)

}
```

I am using AlamofireObjectMapper to fetch data using the method JSONFetch.jsonTest(). Now the problem is how do I call this loadMoreData from my controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684#31608684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do implementing trailing closure here

```
loadMoreData(2){ (result) in

//after completion of your work this closure gets called
 println("your return \(result)")


}
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out before you commented. 
:)

loadMoreData(offset, completion: { (fetched) -> Void in
            if let fetchedData = fetched {
                println("Fetched Data\(fetchedData.count)")
                completion(fetchedData)
            }
            
        })

I did it using like this