# Alamofire Completion Handler returning response + data

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a function that includes a responseObject in it's completion handler. At the moment this returns the json body when I call it, along with any errors.

Some parts of the API I am using however, don't return any data in the response body, they just return a response (200, 404, etc...)

I was thinking about appending the response inside the empty json object that is getting returned, then realised that would be silly and it would probably be better if I returned the `NSHTTPURLResponse` as well, but everything I have found just explains how to return the responseObject along with the error...

**This is the function that returns the completion handler:**

```
func makePostRequest(url : String, params : AnyObject, completionHandler: (responseObject:  NSHTTPURLResponse, JSON?, error: NSError?) -> ())  -> Request? {


    println("params = \(params)")
    return Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)


        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in completionHandler(
            //This is wrong
            response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse,
            responseObject:
            {
                println("Request is \(request)")

                println("Response is \(response)")

                println("Data is \(data)")

                println("Error is \(error)")

                //Append the response to this JSON object?
                //
                var json:JSON = [:]


                if let anError = error
                {

                    println(error)
                }
                else if let data: AnyObject = data
                {

                    json = JSON(data)

                }


                //probably better to return the two...
                //
                return (response, json)

                }(),
            error: error

            )
    }
}
```

**And this is how its used:**

```
networking.makePostRequest(documentUrl, params: docParams) { response, json, error  in


           println("response is: \(response)")

        println("document json: \(json)")

         println("document error: \(error)")



    }
```

I've added in the 'response' bits to all the bits of code, i'm sure this is possible? just not sure how to achieve it..

Comment: thats becuause you are returning `request` not its `respose` follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684#31608684

Comment: that question still only shows how to return one value...

Comment: what do you want in completion handler

Comment: completionHandler: (responseObject:  NSHTTPURLResponse, JSON?, error: NSError?), note the NSHTTPURLResponse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck trying to figure out how to return stuff this way, I solved it like this:

```
 func makePostRequest(url : String, params : AnyObject, completionHandler: (httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse, responseObject:JSON?, error: NSError?) -> ())  -> Request? {


    println("params = \(params)")
    return Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)


        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in completionHandler(
            //This is wrong
            httpResponse: response!,
            responseObject:
            {
                println("Request is \(request)")

                println("Response is \(response)")

                println("Data is \(data)")

                println("Error is \(error)")

                //Append the response to this JSON object?
                //
                var json:JSON = [:]


                if let anError = error
                {

                    println(error)
                }
                else if let data: AnyObject = data
                {

                    json = JSON(data)

                }
                 return json
            }(),
            error: error

            )
    }
}
```

and then calling it like this:

```
 networking.makePostRequest(workDocumentUrl, params: params) { response, json, error  in

        if response.statusCode == 200{
       //do something

        }

        println("json: \(json)")
        println("error: \(error)")



    }
```