# passing array back from a custom framework in alamofire closure

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently writing my first custom framework, however, in my alamofire request, I am not able to pass back my offers. Any advice?

From an app perspective, I am able to append to array in .responseJSON closure then tableView.reloadData()

How do I pass back my array created in my for loop in my .responseJSON closure to my view controller that is using this framework?

Sorry for the newbie question cause this is the first ever framework that I'm writing

```
public class func getVoucherList() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://surprise.com/api/vouchers", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization": "Token " + token, "accept": "application/vnd.audaxy.com.v1"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {

            case .Success:

                let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: json["status"].string, message: json["message"].string, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okAction)

                /*
                for surprise in json["surprise"].arrayValue {
                    offers.append(Offer(offerId: String(surprise["offerid"].intValue), thumbnailUrl: surprise["thumbnail"].string, title: surprise["merchantname"].stringValue, description: surprise["deals"].stringValue, expiryDate: surprise["expire"].stringValue, coverPhotoUrl: surprise["offerimg"].string))
                }
                */

                VAV.getCurrentViewController().presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                    print(offers)
                })
                break

            case .Failure:
                break
            }
    }

}
```

getCurrentViewController is as follow

```
class func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController {
    var topViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

    while ((topViewController?.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        topViewController = topViewController?.presentedViewController
    }
    return topViewController!

}
```

Comment: You want to return `Offers` from responseJSON

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684#31608684

Answer (score 1):

define getVoucherList(callback: ((offers: [Offer])->Void)?){...}

When you are done with the for loop, call the callback function and pass your array back.

In the view controller now you can do what you want with it (i.e. append it to your table data array and reload the table, etc)

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go. Today @happiehappie you are using getVoucherList from a ViewController, but what about using it somewhere else in the project? .. another function that does some processing on the offers and forwards the result somewhere else? .. In this case the code for getting a ViewController will fail miserably :(.

Answer (score 0):

When you are presenting any `UIViewController` then you can pass the data directly. For that, you need to override `prepareForSegue` method. Check out the below example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YOUR_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? YourDestinationController {
            destination.arroffers = offers
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you can pass the data to presenting `UIViewController`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood what you said(again i'm a newbie)
But basically when my app imports this framework, I'll call getVoucherList() in viewDidLoad().

I don't know how to return the array because my array is inside the .responseJSON closure, so I can't just declare
func getVoucherList() -> [Array]

Comment: @Happiehappie can you put some more code? Then I can tell you where you are doing mistake!

Comment: That is basically the only code in my framework. Then when my demo app imported this framework I'll call getVoucherList. My task is to develop the framework and a demo app. So people can just plug this into their swift program and use it