# unexpected non void return value in void function swift

Tags: swift3

The compiler error is unexpected non void return value in void function swift.

```
static func getPhoto(byURL url: String) -> UIImage {
        let photoPrefix = "gs://chatwithroyal-6c9ee.appspot.com/"
        let photoType = ".png"
        let photoURL = photoPrefix + url + photoType
        let image = UIImage()
        FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: photoURL).data(withMaxSize: INT64_MAX, completion: { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading: '\(error)")
                return
            }
            let image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
            return image
        })
    }
```

Any thoughts would be immensely appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `.data()` is asynchronous. You can't return from an asynchronous block. You have to use a callback (completion handler). Please search, there's lots of answers already.

Comment: Can you provide more context please? (where do you call this function). This is crucial in order to know whether this function has to be blocking or it can be accomplished by a completion handler.

Comment: Thank you! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684) works for me