# How can I get value of a Dictionary item from first item of an Array in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have defined **`Dictionary in an Array`** object below:

```
var dataList : [[String:Any]]?
```

And then I have loaded some data in to it. Here is the output when i run this code below:

```
print("DATA LIST:\n \(myRecordList)")
```

Output:

```
Optional([["itemCode": 0, "itemText": please select city], ["itemCode": 1, "itemText": City A], ["itemCode": 2, "itemText": City B], ["itemCode": 3, "itemText": City C], ["itemCode": 4, "itemText": City D], ["itemCode": 5, "itemText": City E], ["itemCode": 6, "itemText": City F]])
```

I would like to reach value of a dictionary from first item in an Array:

As you know, here is the first item in an array:

["itemCode": 0, "itemText": please select city]

And here is the value in above dictionary:

"itemText": **please select city**

After that I would like to set above text ("**please select city**") as a button title if dataList count is not zero:

```
if dataList?.count != 0
{
    **//need help in here!!!**
    {
        self.btnSelectMarkaOutlet.setTitle(tempBtnTitle, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I have tried below scope. But it crushed:

```
    if let newTry = dataList![0]["itemText"] as? [String]
{
    print("here is the output:: \(newTry[0])")
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

let tempBtnTitle = must be "please select city"
I wanted to do this.

**Let me share whole view controller file. Because dataList is nil.**

```
import UIKit

class SinyalSeviyesineGoreAramaYapViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnSelectMarkaOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerViewOutlet: UIPickerView!

    var dataList : [[String:Any]]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("viewDidLoad")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pickerViewOutlet.delegate = self
        self.pickerViewOutlet.dataSource = self

        self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView()

        print("Is the data list nil? : \(self.dataList)")
        if let newTry = self.dataList![0]["itemText"] as? String
        {
            print("here is the output:: \(newTry)")
        }

        //I WANTED TO SET BUTTON TITLE !!
        let tempButtonTitle = ""
        self.btnSelectMarkaOutlet.setTitle(tempButtonTitle, for: .normal)
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let recordName = self.dataList![row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        //return self.cityList![row]

        let info = self.dataList![row]

        if let name = info["itemCode"] as? String,
            let code = info["itemText"] as? String
        {
            let text = "\(name) - \(code)"
            //print("am i here? \(text)")
            return text
        }

        return nil
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataList == nil ? 0 : self.dataList!.count
    }

    func loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView()
    {
        print("loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView method is called")

        ServiceManager.oServiceManager.loadSayacRecords()
            {
                (result) in

                if let sayacRecords = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                {
                    if let resultCodeFromWebApi = sayacRecords?["resultCode"] as? String
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                                print("loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView resultCode: \(resultCodeFromWebApi)")

                                if resultCodeFromWebApi == "999"
                                {
                                    if let myRecordList = sayacRecords?["recordList"] as? [[String:Any]]
                                    {
                                        //DispatchQueue.main.async
                                        //{
                                        self.dataList = myRecordList
                                        print("DATA LIST:\n \(self.dataList)")
                                        self.pickerViewOutlet.reloadAllComponents()
                                        //}
                                    }
                                } // resultCodeFromWebApi == 999 ENDS
                                else
                                {
                                    if let resultMessageFromWebApi = sayacRecords?["resultMessage"] as? String
                                    {
                                        print("resultMessage: \(resultMessageFromWebApi)")
                                    }
                                }
                        } // DispatchQueue.main.async ENDS
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("cant parse it")
                    } // if let resultCodeFromWebApi = loginResult?["resultCode"] as? Int ENDS
                }
        }
    } // loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView ENDS

} // class SinyalSeviyesineGoreAramaYapViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource ENDS
```

Comment: `dataList` is nil, apparently, and you need `as? String` instead of `as? [String]`.

Comment: Dear @Sweeper dataList is nil. That's why I have shared whole viewController file. Can you take a look at why dataList is nil? I am calling loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView() before the 'print("Is the data list nil? : \(self.dataList)")'

Comment: Why is this question tagged with swift5? It looks to me like you are accessing `dataList` before the asynchronous call is done.

Comment: Swift 5 was a mistake. Thanks. I have used DispatchQueue.main.async in loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView() function. Isn't DispatchQueue.main.async fine for the asynchronous issue? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You should use a completion handler (closure) to update your button see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608302/return-value-from-completion-handler-swift/31608684#31608684)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reason would be array is nil and also you are unwrapping with [String] which is String, which may give nil.
Try below to avoid crashes.

```
if dataList?.isEmpty == false,let firstDic = dataList?.first, let neededString = firstDic["itemText"] as? String   {
}
```

Comment: yes datalist was nil. I have extended the question. I have shared whole view controller file after this bold sentence in my question : 'Let me share whole view controller file. Because dataList is nil.' Why is the dataList is nil? How come? I load it as you see before i print it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Dear Pranith, your reply is an solution. But we noticed that dataList is nil. So I have 'asynchronous' problem. I dont want to post another question for this problem. If it is possible can you write me solution for the asynchronous problem. Because dataList is still nil after i call the self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView method in ViewDidLoad. I used DispatchQueue.main.async in this function. But still there is an asynchronous problem. dataList must be loaded after i call self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView method. And then i must try to read itemText from loadaed object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the logic you implemented: the `dataList` is loaded asynchronously, which means that you don't know when it will be available, but you are using it like it's always available.

Example of this error is in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView()

print("Is the data list nil? : \(self.dataList)")
if let newTry = self.dataList![0]["itemText"] as? String
{
    print("here is the output:: \(newTry)")
}
```

With the first line you start to load the `dataList`, but in the `for` loop you are force unwrapping, which means you are saying "Ehi I'm 100% sure it will be available" - which is not true.

A possible solution for your problem is to convert the `dataList!` to `dataList?` everywhere, so if it's not loaded then nothing happens and your app won't crash.

A better and quicker solution is to have a default value for `dataList`, so in case is not loaded you will just react to an empty data model:

```
var dataList : [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()
```

Comment: Dear @Marco Pace I defined it like you wrote: var dataList : [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()  After that i have changed dataList? everywhere like you said. But it gave me an error after  the code line: 'self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView()' Here is the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range  (I think it says dataList is nil. How come can be still nil after i call self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView() function? How can i fix this asynchronously? I wrote DispatchQueue.main.async in function. Don't this fix asynchronously problem?

Comment: That is a different error: you have now an emtpy array, which means it contains 0 elements, but you are getting elements without security checks, like the line self.dataList[0]: you are trying to get element at index 0, but you don't have any index so your program crash.
To avoid crash, you should always check that the arrat has enough element for you to get the index you want. Example: if dataList.count > 0 { let variable = dataList[0] }.
Adding this check will ensure your app doesn't crashes.

Comment: understood. But i dont understand why dataList has not loaded. I call self.loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView() method first and then i check dataList. There is an asynchronous case in here in my logic. How can i fix this? If it is possible can you write me the correct logic to load picker from web api. and set "select city" text as a button title.

Comment: Your logic is perfectly correct, there is nothing to fix: the idea of the asynchronous is that you don't have data and you don't know when they will be available, so you need to add some safety in your code. 
- When everything is available immediately: you can use it immediately
- When data needs to be retrieved (from an API, a database or something else): you need to implement some safety in your code to deal with this uncertain situation.
It's a different problem, but your logic (reload picker when data is available) is correct. Every app does that, that's why you have loading wheels :)

Comment: I have created another function. And then i called this new function in function loadSayacRecordsForTheUIPickerView if i can load dataList. And then it worked. I think i got the asynchronous issue.